# VB.NET debug skips tracing lines unless breakpoint inserted

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am running VS2013 and attempting to step through a debugging session of some simple code. I have added a reference for Adobe Illustrator CS6 Type Library.

1st 2 lines of function called:

```
  Public Function ReturnCastPageItemObject1(pageItem As Object)
    Dim piType = 0
```

When tracing through the code, there is a function call that I can trace to the first line of the function. Sometimes, I can trace to the SECOND statement ONCE, but most times not. Mostly, the debugger 'F11' to step into goes from the first statement and bypasses the 'stepping' of the function and proceeds to the next 'Stop' or breakpoint. It still executes the code in the function, but does not trace it.

The "funny" thing is that if I insert a BREAKPOINT on the second line, everything will trace through properly. I have tries a host of changes everything from changing types, changing variables, moving code from a module to the same class, all to no avail.

Comment: Is it possible you're in `Release` configuration instead of `Debug`?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum Thanks for your reply. No, checked everything and am definitely in debug config. Was there something in particular that gave you that thought? The reason I ask is that maybe it will give me another clue to the problem. Thank you!